# GovTalk / HMRC Transaction Engine Http 1.1 POST error

Tags: c#, xml, post, http-1.1, system.net.httpwebrequest

I appreciate this is a little bit niche, but I thought I would ask anyway. I'm writing a small c# application to utilise the HMRC web portal and electronically submit VAT returns in XML format. According to the HMRC specification it is just a simple Http 1.1 POST action required, and retrieving the response in XML. The application is built, however, I am having trouble with this code. I get an "OK" HttpWebResponse, but the HMRC server returns this spurious error message which they can't seem to tell me what it means. Here is my code:

```
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset='utf-8'";

            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                return responseStr;
            }
```

And the error is:

1001 - The submitted XML document either failed to validate against the GovTalk schema for this class of document or its body was badly formed.

I know the XML is ok, because when I test it using a third-party tool like "Postman" it submits 100% and the Transaction Engine returns no errors, so it must be my code. Does anything look glaringly wrong to post an XML? I have tried different Content/MIME Types and also I have confirmed that 'utf-8' is the correct encoding.

I was just wondering if any developers out there had worked on the Transaction Engine and could share their submit/post code?

Comment: Have you tried System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes?

Comment: also try request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding=utf-8";

Comment: Hello "alg". I have tried System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes, yes, but possibly not tried taking the single quotes out from 'utf-8'. I will try that now. Many thanks for your input. Dave

Comment: No, same error I'm afraid.

Comment: notice 'encoding' as opposed to 'charset' too

Comment: Yes, I spotted that. One thing I did notice..... If I trap the code, I can see that the Bytes read from my XML (ContentLength property) is just 113, and the response I get back is 1024, so much bigger, yet my XML has far more data in it than the XML I get back (at least double).

Comment: Ah, I think I might have figured it out. That code is encoding the string content which is the filename itself, not the contents of the file!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the code converting the file contents into the Byte Array was actually converting the file name.

I changed this line:

```
bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
```

To this:

```
bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(requestXml);
```